# Help Connecting MicroSD Module with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno

I am Trying to make a MicroSD .wav file player using Arduino Uno. I have ordered a MicroSD Card Module from ebay today.

Product Link : http://www.ebay.in/itm/Micro-SD-Card-Module-SD-Storage-Board-TF-Card-Memory-Shield-SPI-For-Arduino-/161696480012?

As You can See in the Product Image, there is **not mentioned on the PCB that which Pin Is ground** or VCC Or any other SPI pin. 
1. How will I identify the correct pins of the MicroSD Module ?
2. How can I connect a speaker to arduino to play .wav files. Is Amplifier neccessary? I am weak when it comes to electronics.

I have listened that when I connect a Capacitor in series with speaker, it will boost the output volume. There will not be music but only voice recordings in .wav files. I want to listen it clearly only.

Comment: [this listing](http://www.ebay.in/itm/Micro-SD-Card-Module-SD-Storage-Board-TF-Card-Memory-Shield-SPI-For-Arduino-/171796652672?hash=item27ffe0e280) has the labels printed on the bottom. Probably identical to your.

Answer (score 1):

OMG, what a vile listing!

Anyway, I think you'll probably find they are in the order listed in the description when the connector is facing south. It's probably printed on the rear of the board which they don't show.

That is, from left to right, GND, VCC, MISO, MOSI, SCK, CS.

As for connecting a speaker, that depends if you want low quality (PWM) audio, or high quality (DAC) audio.  The latter requires the addition of an audio shield, most of which have an SD card slot on them already thus alleviating the need for this SD card breakout board.

For the former there is a library and instructions here: http://www.hackerspace-ffm.de/wiki/index.php?title=SimpleSDAudio

Answer (score 0):

I got my MicroSD Module today. The labels were printed At the bottom side. Dont confuse, CLK = SCK. The VCC goes to arduino 5v.